# How do I define this matrix in matlab?

Tags: matrices, matlab

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 &-1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & -1 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & \dots & 0 & -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$$

How do I write this matrix in matlab?

Comment: type: help diag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there you are:

> A =2*diag(ones(1,n))-diag(ones(1,n-1),-1)-diag(ones(1,n-1),1);

(don't forget to set $n$ before :)

However if you want to evaluate $Av$ for some $v$ you should better **not** define $A$ and use the relations
$$(Av)_i = 2v_i-v_{i-1}-v_{i+1}\qquad \forall  1< i < n$$
$$ (Av)_1 = 2v_{1}-v_2 \qquad (Av)_n= 2v_n-v_{n-1}$$
in your code (it may important for computations speed if $n$ is "large")

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix is a symmetric [Toeplitz matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). There's a [`toeplitz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) function in Matlab, so, for example, a 5-by-5 version of your matrix can be created via:

```
n = 5;
T = toeplitz([2 -1 zeros(1,n-2)])
```

which returns

```
T =

     2    -1     0     0     0
    -1     2    -1     0     0
     0    -1     2    -1     0
     0     0    -1     2    -1
     0     0     0    -1     2
```

Type `edit toeplitz` in your command window to view the code for this function. The solution by @Surb using [`diag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) may be more efficient.

**Update**

For large $n$, a (5 times) faster way to create such a matrix is via the `'tridiag'` option with the `gallery` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html#f84-1000284)) function, which takes advantage of the the sparsity of this matrix:

```
T = full(gallery('tridiag',n,1,2,1));
```

Or, in many cases, you can directly call `spdiags` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html)), which will be even faster:

```
x = zeros(n-1,1)+1;
y = zeros(n,1)+2;
z = x;
T = full(spdiags([[x;0] y [0;z]],-1:1,n,n));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`convmtx`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/convmtx.html) for that:

```
n = 5; %// required number of rows
A = convmtx([-1 2 -1], n);
A = A(:,2:end-1)
```

Example: `n=5` produces

```
A =
     2    -1     0     0     0
    -1     2    -1     0     0
     0    -1     2    -1     0
     0     0    -1     2    -1
     0     0     0    -1     2
```

If you just want to multiply `A` times a column vector `v`, instead of `A*v` it is more effficient to use

```
conv(v, [-1 2 -1], 'same')
```

Comment: Close, and possibly helpful, but the matrix in question is not [circulant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

Comment: @horchler I read the question too fast. Thanks! Corrected now

Comment: Your answer made me realize that there's a function to obtain this matrix directly.

Comment: @horchler Good catch!