# How do I build this band matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matrices, matlab, sparse-matrices

I need to build a pentadiagonal matrix in MATLAB like this:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1+2\lambda & -\lambda_1 & 0 & -\lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
-\lambda_1 & 1+4\lambda_1 & -\lambda_1 & 0 & -\lambda_1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & -\lambda_1 & 1+4\lambda_1 & -\lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & -\lambda_1\\
-\lambda_1 & 0 & -\lambda_1 & 1+4\lambda_1 & -\lambda_1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & -\lambda_1 &0 & -\lambda_1 & 1+4\lambda_1 & \cdots & -\lambda_1 \\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & -\lambda_1 & 0 & -\lambda_1 & \cdots & 1+2\lambda_1\end{pmatrix}$

And once a have this pentadiagional matrix, then I have to build a similar matrix like this:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1-2\lambda & \lambda_1 & 0 & \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\lambda_1 & 1-4\lambda_1 & \lambda_1 & 0 & \lambda_1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \lambda_1 & 1-4\lambda_1 & \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_1\\
\lambda_1 & 0 & \lambda_1 & 1-4\lambda_1 & \lambda_1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \lambda_1 &0 & \lambda_1 & 1-4\lambda_1 & \cdots & \lambda_1 \\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \lambda_1 & 0 & \lambda_1 & \cdots & 1-2\lambda_1\end{pmatrix}$

O know how to build a tridiagonal matrix whit the next code:

```
    lambda1 = dt.*Du./(2.*dx.^2);
  Au = eye(Nx).*(1+2.*lambda1);
  Au(1+1:Nx+1:end) = -lambda1;
  Au(Nx+1:Nx+1:end) = -lambda1;
  Au([1,end]) = 1+lambda1;
```

where $Nx$ is the size of the matrix and $\lambda_1$ is a constant. How can I build this pentadiagonla matrix with this entries?

Comment: The matrix is heptadiagonal, not pentadiagonal.

Answer (score 3):

That band matrix is *almost* a [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) matrix. It is also symmetric. Hence,

```
r = [1+4*lambda1, -lambda1, 0, -lambda1, zeros(1,n-4)];
A = toeplitz(r);
```

Update now the northwest and southeast corners:

```
A(1,1) = 1+2*lambda1;
A(n,n) = 1+2*lambda1;
```

Comment: Yes this is of course simpler. +1

Comment: Related: [Matlab for a Tridiagonal matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1029793/80812).

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as a sum of "diag" commands. For example the code

```
diag([1,1,1],2) + diag([2,2,2,2],1) + diag([3,3,3,3,3],0)
```

gives

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}3&2&1&0&0\\0&3&2&1&0\\0&0&3&2&1\\0&0&0&3&2\\0&0&0&0&3\end{array}\right]$$

of course you can just replace the vectors by "scalar_value * ones(1,N-k)", where k is by how much off the main diagonal we are and N is the dimension of the matrix. For example

```
diag(-lambda_1*ones(1,N-1),1)
```

---

**Edit** if the matrix is going to be very large you may want it to be sparse as many calculations will get faster and will take much less memory for storage, you can then use the sparse command:

```
sparse(rows_,cols_,vals_,N,N)
```

Where the value in vals_(i) will get in position (rows_(i),cols_(i)). Will probably be necessary if matrix larger than a side of thousands or tens of thousands.

Comment: Yes you can add two more terms then. Each term in the sum is a new diagonal.

Comment: Then the code will be?. I'm not understandig your explanation. I mean, I know how to build a tridiagonal matrix with the next code:


lambda1 = 1;
Nx=10;
  Au = eye(Nx).*(1+2.*lambda1);
  Au(1+1:Nx+1:end) = -lambda1;
  Au(Nx+1:Nx+1:end) = -lambda1;
  Au(2+2:Nx+1:end) = -lambda1;
  Au(Nx-1:Nx+1:end) = -lambda1;
  Au([1,end]) = 1+lambda1;
  Au

But how to build the penta diagional matrix?

Comment: You can just take the line with diag commands, add two more diag commands and alter it to get your values in.

Comment: spdiags is the sparse version of diag by the way. No need to compute the correct arguments for sparse.

Comment: @AlexR please help me I can't build the pentadiagonal matrix, it seem to be pretty easy but it doesn't for me

Comment: Yes great observation Alex.